# Covariant metric tensor of a subspace

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products, tensors

Suppose $f_1,f_2$ and $f_3$ are vectors in a vector space $V$ with a dot product. Me assume that the vectors are linearly independent.

> What does it mean to find the **covariant metric tensor** of $\text{span}\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$?

Answer (score 2):

Metric tensor would be the matrix $(g_{ij})$ given by the products $\langle f_i,f_j \rangle$. Covariant means (probably) that matrix (the inverse matrix transforms contravariantly).

Comment: Hm, I thought $(g_{ij})$ is called the "Gram matrix". Is it the same concept in this context?

Comment: In riemmanian geometry, this matrix is the metric matrix, asuming your vectors are a tangent space basis. The metric is a tensor, in an abstract way, and people in physics usually call it metric tensor.

Comment: i have seen the dot product matrix referred to as the gram matrix or even gram(m)ian.